# Why is my alpha pass binary (just 0's and 1's) in Cycles?

Tags: transparency

In Blender Render, my rendered alpha pass has intermediate values (e.g., 0.83) at the boundary -- great for anti-aliasing compositing!

[image]

However, when I switch to Cycles, my alpha channel is always binary, i.e., consisting of only 0's and 1's.

[image]

For some other reasons, I have to stick with Cycles. How would I produce an alpha pass with intermediate values in Cycles?

[image]

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Monochrome is single chroma, single hue in colorspace. The term [Binary image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_image) is correct here. Binary is subset of Grayscale and that is subset of Monochrome.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Since there is an image showing what it is and there is even explanation in brackets in the title, I fail to see the problem you are trying to solve. At least people will learn what Binary image is. *Black&White* is used as synonym for *Grayscale*, it's misleading same as *Monochrome* was. People not understanding something is normal and does not justify avoiding correct terms, it even might spread confusion. *Binary* is the best how to call this and there is no problem with it because this is not a casual site, here you will come across many more technical terms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have only 1 sample set for Cycles:

[image: cycles sampling panel showing render samples set to 1]

Any particular sample in Cycles will return either 1 or 0 for the alpha channel. Antialiased alpha edges are built up by averaging multiple samples, some of which strike the occluding object and some which do not. Using a larger number of samples, such as 16, will fix the issue.

Comment: This is cool. But how many samples are enough? Hmmm.

Comment: That's one of those nebulous "it's enough samples when it's good enough for you" things. Technically, any sample count greater than 1 gives some antialiasing. The more samples, the more antialiasing. There's no way to say definitively when it's enough. 10-20 is a nice ballpark in a lot of cases, but who knows? Rendering is complicated.

Comment: Roughly speaking, ~32 samples will clean up images with only diffuse and no bounce. But usually you'll have much more than that. If you have bounce light, you're looking at ~250 for diffuse to clear up, ~500 for glossy, and anywhere from 1,000-3,000 if you have complex reflections, glass, volumetrics, etc. This can be brought down with certain settings, and the use of the denoiser.